# T-SQL extra column in GROUP BY. How to include in results but exclude from grouping

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have the following SQL

```
SELECT     CNumber, MAX(FormSubmitted), Score
FROM         dbo.vw_MSA
WHERE     (Score IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY CNumber, Score
```

Results:

```
CNumber FormSubmitted                   Score
0011509 2010-09-13 10:22:46.763         11
0016239 2010-09-28 13:53:58.557         8*
0016239 2010-10-12 11:52:33.150         12
0018792 2010-11-02 13:17:37.437         3
0051089 2010-10-07 11:38:29.257         13
0051091 2010-10-01 12:01:30.450         0
0067987 2010-09-29 11:06:48.490         7
0079351 2010-09-30 09:49:10.747         34
0833933 2010-09-30 12:54:19.013         6
0848185 2010-10-07 12:08:42.087         6
5010590 2010-11-01 09:54:14.790         6*
5010590 2010-11-16 15:23:50.350         12
```

I'm sure I should be able to sort this easily but for whatever reason I'm struggling atm.  I need Score included in the results but having this in the GROUP BY inevitably returns more than just the record with the latest FormSubmitted date.  Can anyone help me out in updating this query so I will get the Score in the results but only those records that are the maximum FormSubmitted date i.e exclude those marked *?

Comment: Can you pust desired record set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     A.CNumber, A.FormSubmitted, A.Score
FROM         dbo.vw_MSA A
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT CNumber, MAX(FormSubmitted) AS MaxSubmitted 
FROM dbo.vw_MSA
WHERE     (Score IS NOT NULL)
GROUP BY CNumber) AS B
ON A.CNumber = B.CNumber AND A.FormSubmitted = B.MaxSubmitted
```

Comment: TYVM.  I really need to brush up my SQL mojo!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `(CNumber, FormSubmitted)` is guaranteed to be unique:

```
SELECT T1.CNumber, T1.FormSubmitted, T1.Score
FROM dbo.vw_MSA T1
JOIN
(
    SELECT CNumber, MAX(FormSubmitted) AS MaxFormSubmitted
    FROM dbo.vw_MSA
    WHERE Score IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY CNumber
) T2
ON T1.CNumber = T2.CNumber
AND T1.CNumber = T2.MaxFormSubmitted
```